# R plotly show xcoordinate on xaxis

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to create a graph with a similar x-axis format to this (from https://plot.ly/r/line-charts/):

code given:

```
library(plotly)

x <- c(1:100)
random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
data <- data.frame(x, random_y)

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
```

[image: graph]

However, running the code on my machine produces this graph:

[image]

Notice that the x-coordinate hover is not there.

R version: 3.4.1
Plotly version: 4.7.1

Changing the `hoverinfo` and `text` tags in `plot_ly` just changes the hoverinfo over the graph. How do I show the same hovering x-coordinate in the first graph?

**Update:** setting `hoverinfo = "text+x"` and `layout(hovermode = "x")` shows the x-coordinate on the x-axis and the point tooltips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting [`hovermode`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-hovermode) to `'x'`

```
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>% layout(hovermode = 'x')
```

and it should work.

Comment: After playing around a little, it seems that `hovermode` shows all points on the graph with the same x-coordinate, but doesn't show the actual x-coordinate on the x-axis (as seen in the first picture). Could it be a version problem?

Comment: Strange... I have exactly the same versions. Which OS are you on?

Comment: MacOS Sierra: 10.12.6.

Comment: It looks like hovermode needs to be set to "x", and hoverinfo needs to be set to "text+x" for it to work.